# Google reCAPTCHA is not working

Tags: php, forms, captcha, recaptcha

I integrated Google Recaptcha to my website.

However, people can still fill the form and send mail without completing the captcha. (So they do not have to solve any puzzles they can just get straight through which is leaving me vunerable to bots of course)

So, I basically need PHP code that checks to see if the users has actually "Ticked" or "Completed" the Recaptcha. So then they can proceed to send mail.

**Here is my PHP form code:**

```
 <!-- Start Contact Form -->

<div id="contact-form" class="contatct-form">
<div class="loader"></div>
<form method="post" action="mail.php">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<label for="name">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
<span class="name-missing">Please enter your name</span>
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" size="60">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<label for="e-mail">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
<span class="email-missing">Please enter a valid e-mail</span>
<input id="e-mail" name="email" type="text" value="" size="60">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<label for="url">Website</label>
<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="" size="80">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<label for="message">Add Your Comment</label>
<span class="message-missing">Say something!</span>
<textarea id="message" name="message" cols="45" rows="10"></textarea>
</br>
 <!--Google  reCAPTCHA-->
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "My Public Key"; // you got this from the signup page
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
<!--End Google  reCAPTCHA-->
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send Message" onclick="return valtest();">
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Here is my mail.php code:**

```
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "My private key";
$resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
if (!$resp->is_valid) {
  // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
  die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
     "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
} else {
  $sendto = "myemail@domain.com";
$name=$_REQUEST['name']; 
$usermail = $_REQUEST['email']; 
$url=$_REQUEST['url']; 
$content  = nl2br($_POST['message']); 
$subject  = "Web Enquiry"; 
$headers  = "From: " . strip_tags($name) . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($usermail) . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8 \r\n"; 
$msg  = "<html><body style='font-family:Arial,sans-serif;'>"; 
$msg .= "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>New    Enquiry</h2>\r\n"; 
$msg .= "<p><strong>Sent by:</strong> ".$usermail."</p>\r\n"; 
$msg .= "<p><strong>Client Name:</strong> ".$name."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Message:</strong> ".$content."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Contact:</strong> ".$url."</p>\r\n";
$msg .= "</body></html>";
mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, $headers);
echo "<script>window.location =\"index.php\";</script>";
```

**Here is recaptchalib.php Code:**

```
 <?php
 /**
 * This is a PHP library that handles calling reCAPTCHA.
 *    - Documentation and latest version
 *          https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php
 *    - Get a reCAPTCHA API Key
 *          https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
 *    - Discussion group
 *          http://groups.google.com/group/recaptcha
 *
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2014, Google Inc.
 * @link      http://www.google.com/recaptcha
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
  * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
  * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
  * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
  * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
  *
  * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
   * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
    *
    * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
      * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
       * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
      * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
       * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
      * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
       * THE SOFTWARE.
          */
          /**
          * A ReCaptchaResponse is returned from checkAnswer().
          */
           class ReCaptchaResponse
            {
            public $success;
             public $errorCodes;
              }
              class ReCaptcha
                {
                 private static $_signupUrl = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin";
                  private static $_siteVerifyUrl =
                   "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?";
                  private $_secret;
               private static $_version = "php_1.0";
              /**
 * Constructor.
 *
 * @param string $secret shared secret between site and ReCAPTCHA server.
 */
function ReCaptcha($secret)
{
    if ($secret == null || $secret == "") {
        die("To use reCAPTCHA you must get an API key from <a href='"
            . self::$_signupUrl . "'>" . self::$_signupUrl . "</a>");
    }
    $this->_secret=$secret;
}
/**
 * Encodes the given data into a query string format.
 *
 * @param array $data array of string elements to be encoded.
 *
 * @return string - encoded request.
 */
private function _encodeQS($data)
{
    $req = "";
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $req .= $key . '=' . urlencode(stripslashes($value)) . '&';
    }
    // Cut the last '&'
    $req=substr($req, 0, strlen($req)-1);
    return $req;
}
/**
 * Submits an HTTP GET to a reCAPTCHA server.
 *
 * @param string $path url path to recaptcha server.
 * @param array  $data array of parameters to be sent.
 *
 * @return array response
 */
 private function _submitHTTPGet($path, $data)
  {
    $req = $this->_encodeQS($data);
    $response = file_get_contents($path . $req);
    return $response;
  }
  /**
   * Calls the reCAPTCHA siteverify API to verify whether the user passes
   * CAPTCHA test.
   *
   * @param string $remoteIp   IP address of end user.
   * @param string $response   response string from recaptcha verification.
    *
    * @return ReCaptchaResponse
    */
     public function verifyResponse($remoteIp, $response)
     {
    // Discard empty solution submissions
    if ($response == null || strlen($response) == 0) {
        $recaptchaResponse = new ReCaptchaResponse();
        $recaptchaResponse->success = false;
        $recaptchaResponse->errorCodes = 'missing-input';
        return $recaptchaResponse;
    }
    $getResponse = $this->_submitHttpGet(
        self::$_siteVerifyUrl,
        array (
            'secret' => $this->_secret,
            'remoteip' => $remoteIp,
            'v' => self::$_version,
            'response' => $response
        )
    );
    $answers = json_decode($getResponse, true);
    $recaptchaResponse = new ReCaptchaResponse();
    if (trim($answers ['success']) == true) {
        $recaptchaResponse->success = true;
    } else {
        $recaptchaResponse->success = false;
        $recaptchaResponse->errorCodes = $answers [error-codes];
    }
    return $recaptchaResponse;
    }
 }
 ?>
```

**When I replace**

```
      <!--Google  reCAPTCHA-->
      <?php
      require_once('recaptchalib.php');
      $publickey = "My Site Key"; // you got this from the signup page
      echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
       ?>
      <!--End Google  reCAPTCHA-->
```

**with**

```
             <!--Google  reCAPTCHA-->
             <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My Site key"></div>
             <!--End Google  reCAPTCHA-->
```

**it will display the widget but people can still fill the form and send mail without completing the captcha.**

Comment: `</br>` is not a closing tag

Comment: google has changed some code functions in v2 you have to use them also

Comment: post screenshot how you are getting the output

Comment: In my contact-us.php page Google reCAPTCHA widget is not displaying.

Comment: When I replace the following code with <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My Site key"></div> it is displaying the widget but people can still fill the form and send mail without completing the captcha.


<!--Google  reCAPTCHA-->
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "My Public Key"; // you got this from the signup page
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
<!--End Google  reCAPTCHA-->

Comment: @Hera have a look at my answer i think it will help you :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to check if the recaptcha isset:

```
<?php

$errMsg = "";
$succMsg = "";

/**************************/
/* GOOGLE reCAPTCHA START */
/**************************/
require_once '../../reCAPTCHA/autoload.php';
$siteKey = 'sitekey';
$secret = 'secretkey';
/************************/
/* GOOGLE reCAPTCHA END */
/************************/

if ((isset($_POST['submit']) | !empty($_POST["submit"]))) {

    if ((isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) && !empty($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"])) {

        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
        $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        if ($resp->isSuccess()) {

            $succMsg = "Success Message";

            /**
             * DO THE DB ENTRIES HERE
             */

        }

    } else {

        $errMsg = "Error With Captcha";
    }
}
?>
```

**and you will need [these](https://ufile.io/fbe84) files from google.

they are loaded here: `require_once '../../reCAPTCHA/autoload.php';`**

your form page should look like:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<div id="contact-form" class="contatct-form">
    <div class="loader"></div>
    <form method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <?php
                if (isset($succMsg)) {
                    echo $succMsg;
                } else {
                    echo "";
                }
                if (isset($errMsg)) {
                    echo $errMsg;
                } else {
                    echo "";
                }
            ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="name">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <span class="name-missing">Please enter your name</span>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" size="60">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="e-mail">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <span class="email-missing">Please enter a valid e-mail</span>
                <input id="e-mail" name="email" type="text" value="" size="60">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="url">Website</label>
                <input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="" size="80">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <label for="message">Add Your Comment</label>
                <span class="message-missing">Say something!</span>
                <textarea id="message" name="message" cols="45" rows="10"></textarea>
                <br>
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $siteKey; ?>"></div>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send Message" onclick="return valtest();">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130103/discussion-on-answer-by-blueblazer172-google-recaptcha-is-not-working).

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my Contact page:**

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><html lang="en" class="no-js"> <![endif]-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Basic -->
<title> </title>
<!-- Define Charset -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<!-- Responsive etatag -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<!-- Page Description-->
<meta name="Description"">
<meta name="keywords"  ">
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, FOLLOW">
<meta name="author" content=" ">
<meta name="googlebot" content="noodp">
<link rel="canonical" href=" "/>
<!-- CSS Styles  -->
<?php
?>
<!-- CSS Styles END-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function valtest()
{
var name=document.getElementById('name').value;
var email=document.getElementById('e-mail').value;
var url=document.getElementById('url').value;
var message=document.getElementById('message').value;
if((name==null||name==""))
{
alert("Please Enter Name");
return false;
}
if((email==null||email==""))
{
alert("Please Enter email");
return false;
}
else
{
alert('Thank you for Send The Details');

return true;
}
}
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
</head>
<body oncontextmenu="return false" ondragstart="return false" onselectstart="return false">
<!-- Container -->
<div id="container">
<!-- Start Header -->
<div class="hidden-header"></div>
<header class="clearfix">
<!-- Start Top Bar -->
<?php include_once(); ?>
<!-- End Top Bar -->
<!-- Start Header ( Logo & Naviagtion ) -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<!-- Stat Toggle Nav Link For Mobiles -->
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</button>
<!-- End Toggle Nav Link For Mobiles -->
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img alt="" src="images/margo.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<!-- Start Navigation List -->
<!-- End Navigation List -->
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End Header ( Logo & Naviagtion ) -->
</header>
<!-- End Header -->
<!-- Start Page Banner -->
<!-- End Page Banner -->
<!-- Start Content -->
<div id="content">
<div class="container">
<div class="page-content">
<div class="col-md-8">
<!-- Classic Heading -->
<h4 class="classic-title"><span>Contact Us</span></h4>
<!-- Start Contact Form -->
<div id="contact-form" class="contatct-form">
<div class="loader"></div>
<form method="post">
<div class="row">
<?php
if (isset($succMsg)) {
echo $succMsg;
} else {
echo "";
}
if (isset($errMsg)) {
echo $errMsg;
} else {
echo "";
}
?>
<div class="col-md-4">
<label for="name">Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
<span class="name-missing">Please enter your name</span>
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" value="" size="60">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<label for="e-mail">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
<span class="email-missing">Please enter a valid e-mail</span>
<input id="e-mail" name="email" type="text" value="" size="60">
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
<label for="url">Website</label>
<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="" size="80">
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<label for="message">Add Your Comment</label>
<span class="message-missing">Say something!</span>
<textarea id="message" name="message" cols="45" rows="10"></textarea>
<br>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo $siteKey; ?>"></div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send Message" onclick="return valtest();">
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<br/>
<!-- End Contact Form -->
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">

<!-- Classic Heading -->
<h4 class="classic-title"><span>Head Office</span></h4>

<!-- Divider -->
<div class="hr1" style="margin-bottom:10px;"></div>

<!-- Info - Icons List -->
<ul class="icons-list">
</ul>

<div class="hr1" style="margin-bottom:50px;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- End content -->
<!-- Start Map -->
<!-- End Map -->
<!-- Start Footer -->
<?php
include_once('footer.php');
?>
<!-- End Footer -->
</div>
<!-- End Container -->
<!-- Go To Top Link -->
<a href="#" class="back-to-top"><i class="fa fa-angle-up"></i></a>
<div id="loader">
<div class="spinner">
<div class="dot1"></div>
<div class="dot2"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should delete that answer cause it is none. Put this content in your question.